# How to maintain composure when a dedicated employee gets fired without any proper clarification?

Tags: psychology

This can happen in any workplace especially in those workplaces where a collaborative  mindset suddenly gets invaded by autocratic and top-down mindset and new rules are forced on people, with examples being made of those who disagree. This can happen to anyone and I know I don't have enough composure myself to remain calm and so cool as other people.

What are the tips and psychology tidbits I should keep in mind to be mentally ready to face any situation myself in future?

Comment: I see we sorted this out... removing my comments to cut noise

Comment: Thanks all for letting me edit and fit question for the site

Comment: I like to repeat the mantra, “it’s just a job” in my head.

Comment: The most important thing about being fired is to not worry about the company that fired you.  When you worked for them, they paid you to worry about the company.  The instant they stopped paying you, you shouldn't give them any space in your mind.

Answer (score 8):

When treated unfairly, the most important thing to remember is that you have done nothing wrong.  False accusations, and abusive management can cause us to question ourselves.

1. The first thing to do is to avoid asking your self the question "What
   could I have done differently?" or "What did I do to provoke this".Sometimes managers are just bad people.  Organizations can go in different directions, things go wrong, and the regime needs a scapegoat.
2. Know when to walk away:  if upper management is behind the decision, there will be no appeal to reason, no fairness, and no mercy.  Pack your bags, it's time to leave.
3. Look to your peers for guidance.  This will help keep you centered.  If you are being reassured by your peers, you will be less likely to blame yourself.
4. Keep things positive.  Remember that you are the same person you were yesterday.  While your time at this given job/organization may be over, that's a reflection on THEM not you.
5. start networking.  A CEO I once knew gave me this advice:  Collect people and ask for help.  You'd be amazed at what kind of help can come from nowhwere

Comment: Yes but the termination in any scenario can be misleading to future jobs one applies to. And that damage of image and rep is irreversible, making things more negative

Comment: @CoderKaran I went through something similar myself, and I agree, it is very important to avoid that negativity as much as you can.  Sometimes you need to accept it, rise above it, and move on

Comment: I like this answer in general, but I think (after letting some time go by) it's worth reflecting a little and gaining more understanding.  But for sure, remember that you are still a worthwhile person.  And yes, help can come from nowhere.  I was out of work and went to a show with a friend, happened to sit next to someone I knew and he gave me contact info.  Be open, a lot of people really want to help out.

Comment: @DaveG True story:  I was out of work and taking a few courses at a county college.  I was helping this fellow out with a few problems   We got to talking and I mentioned that I was out of work.  He gave me his brother's information.  His brother owned a consulting company, and I was working within the week.

Comment: Disagree with #1: Self-reflection is important and this answer seems to give license to blame "management" for problems that may be partially or wholly the fault of the firee. That being said, "It is possible to commit no mistakes and still lose."

Answer (score 7):

If it's you who got fired, you look for a new job or get professional legal advice if you think it's both unfair and you can win a legal battle. If it's someone else, then you don't know the full story, and mind your own business.

Many places anyone can get fired at any time, some places with no reason given at all. They may have legal recourse, but observers usually don't.

Answer (score 1):

> where a collaborative mindset suddenly gets invaded by autocratic and top-down mindset

You need to understand that, if you give your time and work to a company, the product of the work belongs to the company. The company does not owe you anything.

> What are the tips and psychology tidbits I should keep in mind to be mentally ready to face any situation myself in future?

That said, it is also true that the relationships you build, the experience you had is yours. As well as is the decision whether you keep working for said company or not. And while the company does not owe you anything, you don't owe the company either. You decide for yourself, whether you are still happy at that place, or whether you want to move on.